# Special characters in Request URL in SoapUI

Tags: http, soapui

I use `SoapUI` to send HTTP and SOAP requests. There is an URL like this: https://mydomain/response? , where a HTTP request should be posted. URL in raw request view it appears without question mark. I tried to provide it in URL encoded(`%3F`) form too, but it is not resolved, it points to a different URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a GET string.

Anything after the "?" will be the parameters.

You don't have anything after the "?". Thus no parameters.

For some reason, this makes soapui remove it. But it really should be without any consequence. Both https://mydomain/response? and https://mydomain/response will reach the same endpoint with no parameters.